# Pan controls & toggling on / off draggable using double or single click events? Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps, events, navigation, click, toggle

Would anyone happen to know how to go about toggling a click event to turn 'draggable' on and off, so click once and it becomes draggable, click again and it becomes inactive?

Keeping draggable on constantly can become an issue on mobile devices.

```
map.addListener('click', function() {  
    map.set('draggable', true);  
});
```

Above works well, but how would I make it toggle back to off on the next click event? or maybe even turn on with double click (tap twice) and off again the same way?

.

> Quick Note: *My original question was about the Pan control feature on Google Maps V3, but as the first response shows it has since been depreciated.*

Comment: You should have left your question unedited, marked @scaisEdge 's answer as the accepted answer and asked another question because maybe others find your original question also useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set a proper window scope var

```
var isDraggable = true;
```

the in you listener  test the state of isDraggable and change

```
map.addListener('click', function() {  
  if (isDraggable ) then {
     map.set('draggable', false);  
    isDraggable = false; 
   } else{
     map.set('draggable', true);  
    isDraggable = truen; 
  }
});
```

Comment: Anyway  .. have posted an answer also for the new question  hope is useful.

Answer (score 2):

For pan Control you should use panControl  .. but starting with v3.22 seems is deprecated by google  https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v322-controls-diff#overview-map-control-deprecated

```
function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('footer-map'), {
  center: {lat: -37.111, lng: 144.888},
  zoom: 14,
  scrollwheel: false,
  draggable: false, 
  disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
  panControl:true,
  navigationControl: true,
  navigationControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
  }
});
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I will update the original question with a possible new way to do this, seeing as the pan is not available.

Comment: Well change the question after you have obtained a proper answer is not .. fair ..  ..  the correct way was rate propely the orginal question a post a new question with the new content ..

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to ask it to you here in the comments instead, but I couldn't get the formatting working, it just appeared in one big chunk. When I went to "Answer Question" it said " Edit your question if you need to add more details. ", I thought that meant it was commonplace to do so, I'm new here so still trying to understand how things work.

Comment: I've now edited the main question so it helps others who may be searching for either topic

Comment: No problem .. normally a question is closed without change and a a new one is opened for the new question .. ..but ayway i have answered  to your new question